# Android studio project files' content corrupted

Tags: android

I face a problem. I don't know why it happens. Sometimes my project file are corrupted if i open them in android studio . Their content change to characters that I don't know where they come from. This is a sample:

```
<component name="libraryTable">


 <library name="Gradle: com.android.support:drawerlayout-28.0.0-alpha1">
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/drawerlayout-28.0.0-alpha1.aar/f65a939895672f396c5831b3b24607b0/res" />
      <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/transforms-1/files-1.1/drawerlayout-28.0.0-alpha1.aar/f65a939895672f396c5831b3b24607b0/jars/classes.jar!/" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC />
    <SOURCES>
      <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.android.support/drawerlayout/28.0.0-alpha
```

another files content:

```
   �PNG


IHDR   $   $   � ��  �IDATx�ݘ�N�0�+���DDlx�<G��L�lH��Xy��lU�lHv�S�;���㏤=�J�Ͽ��=����=�'���7sx�h�w�߰ʹm{pU���O�    �����nz���Ķ������)����}�G2H�h��J^�Z��A,0�B_�3
�ݿ3�� ��O���<>Lgڷ/J:�2�R^ӧ���0F)k0�FY����\�C{W0�p��<�   ,*�$�$�:yZk����>Ƕj�.{±�j�)����k�r)�]�a�i��+B���'�|̈́:�.=��x���;�q��+/�=�x�V3��P4�Je�0F�2ȡ���
4e��X��)+�C�(�`�E��.�D��'���ŕ��������&��1��A��Q��e���V;z>:c����b�    IEND�B`�
```

this a java file :((. Every time for this issue I have to make the project again and add files to it. Also I don't know search for what in google. 
** Invalidate cash and restart didn't solve my problem.
thanks for any help

Comment: Be sure, you're not using a Dropbox/GDrive folder as a source folder for the project.

Comment: No I don't use.

Comment: I put a project on github I don't know this problem is related to it or not. But after that I face to this problem. (this project is not on github).

Comment: that's a weird issue. Can you tell me this code comes in your java class or gradle ?. Looking at the code it looks like there is problem with your imports of DrawerLayout.

Comment: It's my java file. I edit the question and show you another file content. If I open the file with a text editor It show the correct content. and also I can run the project without any error

Comment: I didn't find the  true solution but updating the android studio solved the problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio shows wrong file contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249677/android-studio-shows-wrong-file-contents)