# Unresolved class MainActivity

Tags: java, android-studio

I encountered a problem while using Android Studio. When I'm trying to run any app, I get the same error "Default activity not found", and in my code in line `tools:context=".MainActivity"`, MainActivity is highlighted red and it says "Unresolved class MainActivity". It happens even if I create a brand new "empty activity".

So far I've tried:

- refreshing IDE cache
- checked package names in Android manifest and MainActivity
- selecting a default activity in-app configuration
- made sure that src is the source directory

I've also noticed that in my "most advanced" app the `build.gradle` looks like this:

[image: Screenshot]

Android manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.justjava">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Project directory + code:

[image: dir]

activity main xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/coffee_grains"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300sp"
        android:contentDescription="Coffee Grains"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/coffee_grains"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/cup"
        android:layout_width="120sp"
        android:layout_height="170sp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/cup"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/coffee_grains" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quantity"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="quantity"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/cup"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/coffee_grains" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/cup"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/quantity">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/plus"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:onClick="increment"
            android:text="+" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/quantity_text_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8sp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/miuns"
            android:layout_width="48dp"
            android:layout_height="48dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            android:onClick="decrement"
            android:text="-" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/price"
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="order summary"
        android:textAllCaps="true"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/cup"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/linearLayout" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/order_summary_text_view"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="0$"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/cup"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/price" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="100sp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:onClick="submitOrder"
        android:text="order"
        android:textSize="16sp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@id/cup"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/order_summary_text_view" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Main Activity file:

```
package com.example.justjava;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * This app displays an order form to order coffee.
 */
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int quantity = 1;
    double pricePerCup = 2.90;
    String name = "Pawel";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    public void increment(View view) {
        quantity = quantity +1;
        displayQuantity(quantity);
    }
    public void decrement(View view) {
        quantity = quantity - 1;
        displayQuantity(quantity);
    }
    private String createOrderSummary(double price){
        String orderSummary = "Name: " + name + "\nQuantity: " + quantity + 
    "\nTotal price: $" + price + "\nThanks!";
        return orderSummary;
    }

    private double calculatePrice(int count, double price){
        return count*price;
    }

    /**
     * This method displays the given text on the screen.
     */
    private void displayMessage(String message) {
        TextView orderSummaryTextView = 
    findViewById(R.id.order_summary_text_view);
        orderSummaryTextView.setText(message);
    }
    /**
     * This method is called when the order button is clicked.
     */
    public void submitOrder(View view) {
        double totalPrice = calculatePrice(quantity, pricePerCup);
        String priceMessage = createOrderSummary(totalPrice);
        displayMessage(priceMessage);
    }

    /**
     * This method displays the given quantity value on the screen.
     */
    private void displayQuantity(int number) {
        TextView quantityTextView = findViewById(R.id.quantity_text_view);
        quantityTextView.setText("" + number);
    }

}
```

Comment: please add a manifest file

Comment: and directory image and XML file

Comment: Manifest added. What do you mean by directory image?

Comment: project directory in android studio

Comment: mainAtivity `XML` file also

Comment: Try to clean and rebuild project, also are you sure you did not place MainActivity under some directory? else you would refer like `tools:context=".folderName.MainActivity"`

Comment: `tools:context=".folderName.MainActivity"` or you just remove this line in `XML` file of main activity

Comment: I'll check that. Meanwhile I added the code to the post.

Comment: MainActivity is in app/src/main/java/com/example/justjava where justjava is the name of my app

Comment: please look at my answer @Pawel

Comment: Besides, the problem persists even if I create a brand new project with a new empty activity.

Comment: when you're referring context you will whole src directory in XML otherwise just remove this line

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio shows wrong file contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249677/android-studio-shows-wrong-file-contents)

Answer (score 11):

use this line `MainActivity XML` fle

```
tools:context="com.example.justjava.MainActivity"
```

You are not referring in XML whole src directory.

**OR**

Just remove this line from `XML`

```
tools:context=".folderName.MainActivity"
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187821/discussion-on-answer-by-tanveer-munir-unresolved-class-mainactivity).

Answer (score 8):

1.Rebuild project, if not solved

2.Go to the `File menu`, then click on the `Invalidate Caches/Restart` option then `Invalidate and Restart`.

Your `ide` will be automatically restarted and the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 2):

Replace this line of code:

`<activity android:name="MainActivity"/>`

with this:

`<activity android:name="com.example.justjava.MainActivity"/>`

Answer (score 1):

In my experience this happens because mistakes in the code, often in naming classes.

I solved this issue just fixing the namespace in the MainActivity class, indeed I made a mistake just there because I copied and pasted the content from another project.

Answer (score 1):

I have also seen this same error.  In my experience, this error can happen in the event the 'package' statement at the top of the MainActivity file (I was using kotlin at the time) is incorrect or missing.  Consider checking this statement to make sure nothing is amiss.

Answer (score 0):

This problem has happened to me as well, I used a program-incompatible library ,Removing that library solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for this problem in **FLUTTER**. For native user, you **can** try to do something similar.

Step 1 : Open this folder of your flutter project (It contains some file like app-debug, etc. As seen in image.). This is the folder where debug app stored with some of its additional files.

**{Project Location}\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk**

Example - Folder location of my test App.

C:\Users\DeLL\fp\fd\test\build\app\outputs\flutter-apk

Step 2 : **Delete** everything.

Step 3 : Re-Run App.

Note : Sometimes you may need to repeat this step 2 times. Be patience. Hope it may help you.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eULFl.png)

Answer (score 0):

I've been trying to fix this problem for a while and I didn't find any resolves.

I still don't know why this problem occurs but doing this solved my problem.

1- Create a new package 
2- Drag your activity into this package and run your application

Answer (score -1):

Make your SDK version about higher like 16 or above you can get to

If you're SDK version is 14 in the gradle file(app module)