# After Android Studio Update Suddenly my Java & Xml file changed

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Java File Show like below

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqoOl.png)

[image]

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xqoOl.png)

[image]

Xml file show like below

[Before](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYp3H.png)

[image]

[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GPoE.png)

[image]

I have tried clear Project, Rebuild Project, Restart/Invalidate, delete Build,.idea folders but its doesn't work.

Comment: Looks like corruption. Double-check with any editor that isn't Android Studio to check if the file system is affected too

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio shows wrong file contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249677/android-studio-shows-wrong-file-contents)

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/54044993/7666442

Comment: Thank you @NileshRathod

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**I have tried below solution and its work for me.**

I have delete caches folder from **C: Drive**.

```
C:\Users\admin\.AndroidStudio3.3\system\caches
```