# Android Studio 3.3 corrupted all the project files in new bug

Tags: android-studio

After updating Android Studio to the latest 3.3 version everything was going fine until suddenly gradle build failed, then indexing failed because can't read the idea files. I opened the .imi file and surprise! the contents have been replaced with some Apache2 license! Not just that every single xml file in the project is now an Apache license with length as every file also every Java/SQL file is now Chinese gibberish with a UTF-8 error on top which is also unrelated.

Anyway on the system file explorer and every file is correct.
The bug isn't related to the build or idea or any file inside the project or any program file (the problem will persist reinstalling Android Studio).

EDIT: there was a similar problem in the past but the glitch was reintroduced in Android Studio 3.3

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio shows wrong file contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249677/android-studio-shows-wrong-file-contents)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The solution is to manually erase the contents of this folder:

Windows

```
C:\Users\user\.AndroidStudio3.3\system\caches
```

Linux/Mac

```
~/.AndroidStudio3.3/system/caches
```

And restart the program.