# Android Manifest: Unexpected Tokens

Tags: android-studio, utf-8, unexpected-token

I opened my app to start developing on it today, and when I loaded it, it wasn't able to be run because of an issue in the manifest file. Taking a look inside the manifest file, i get this:

```
PK     A                   META-INF/ PK     A (M��?   T      META-INF/MANIFEST.MF�M��LK-.�
K-*��ϳR0�3����-�I�M�+I,
�d��Z)�%��b�µ���r�r PK     A               org/ PK     A               org/gradle/ PK     A               org/gradle/wrapper/ PK     A �zZ��  �   -   org/gradle/wrapper/BootstrapMainStarter.class�VYw�V�˖#DgH!��bSJiIh
�   �@c5�žv���2$����ڗ����Sz���?B;W�op��s�ٿ�;#����g ^�O2Bx[�a�KX�pA� .�X�%���˒�e\�U���
����&Ẅ)�X�pCƻ�H���X�p+�����|y�/w�Pe�#+!�Ǽ�C(H�8��='���
�f� �Ni[.יuM]׉J�YU_U-��kD���Jb)�*$
���Y⁥nn2+q�4�M�%U3Ҷj�̚�/ѵ�]����U��Hۖff]�f&4��:�V�<�� �./�E���QY@�˽�Z}�4l�e'u�TJ�j�1�j�N\_Iձ�r��vHz�|;$�a��  X,����py$9ؘ��M/y��f�L�q��[Y�ik�Q��Q)�K�e#��,�p�)O��ż�TG���d`���3�¢��r�,[Y��h��.�-(8�Q3 �^�:J=G�]ܓ�+(`*��
,���q_�l0zFq�jq��8~���Xl�C����`5eO�G�X@�.���]���O|�Ϩ�^��Yb�
>Ǩr-?�  �����B���J�C|M�ݸ������(+��o|����z^)�Vd;�0�4�z.b�vD��`����".��g3r��JD3<rN�2h�en!2>V�+�?��~0�?{��g7�����y}�^@O4V����%\�I�Z$S$9�T�����.٬��q��f
�]�}U��A�!�
������+��
��ԏ{�e����
n]*���d��0}��N�ε�0m�J- kмYq���Z�N�ee��x4�5�y����z7n#4���b�$�w����Ѧ9���z���'e4�2l$���    �X��)��L#��jSC�Łv)�I@�EBM@��
��m���g�0}����y��[�v�v�D�c:t`�րC܏c�*� ���2&H�+?'9����T�O�ˈ@���+�WH?�TA����  �X���R*�;��C]$ݝ���']A�L ���&��w#,���G\�7x�ϣ;�NZ���r���?�a\�V�mˈã��FX���&1� �cqB�JC�l�"���[F$k'��UB�m��k$u����:�� �H��d�� ��V�c���O1���bᥩgs�S�x�g�L
�'x*
```

I assume that this is some sort of encoding file issue, I've tried reverting back to previous versions of my project from days ago when it was working and it only shows the encoded version of my manifest file. Is there any way I can turn this back into my correct manifest file?

I am using the newest version of android studio.

Any help is appreciated, 
thanks

Comment: Seems like the same problem as e.g. [Android Studio shows wrong file contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249677/android-studio-shows-wrong-file-contents) and [How to fix severe bugs in android studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54938435/how-to-fix-severe-bugs-in-android-studio).