# How to solve "Element project must be declared" issue in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I usually run my apps without any kind of problems. But, recently, I faced this problem in colors.xml : "Element project must be declared"..... How can I solve it???

[oi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LDeOi.jpg)

Comment: That doesn't look like the correct format for `colors.xml` at all. It should comprose of a number of `<color>` tags contained within a `<resources>` tag. How did you get your file in that state in the first place?

Comment: This is an example of what a `colors.xml` file should look like: https://gist.github.com/sghael/2930380

Comment: Dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249677/android-studio-shows-wrong-file-contents

Comment: @Zoe Good catch! I thought that had been resolved by now?

Comment: @MichaelDodd possibly, but if that's the case, I'm assuming that's an rc patch and not a full release. And even then, rollout is slow

Comment: @MichaelDodd I don't know how did I get this file. I didn't even edit it. I was learning Android Development, I run the app like ordinary and I got that problem....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This color file in your picture is not so related to `colors.xml` - it should look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#795548</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#6B4A3E</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#FF000000</color
</resources>
```

Comment: Okeyyy, Thaaanks