# Is it me? Or android studio changed my whole build.gradle codes now my whole project is messed up now?

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

I was coding my android program on Android Studio and I made quite a progress on it. I remember I copied all the codes in my `colors.xml` (ctrl+A) when this happened. I was thinking to change the background image of my app so I deleted my background image in my drawable folder unchecking the "safe delete" option.

When the background image was deleted, I put another image using batch drawable import hoping that it would exchange the background image of my app, but it didn't. I tried to change the background image by linking the image in my code in the layout folder, same results. So I thought I could invalidate caches and restart hoping to fix the problem.

To my surprise my whole project was a mess, the errors where from my build gradle, all of the codes were changed! It was replaced by the codes used in the colors.xml

[image]

Now I can't do anything, I think I'm going to redo the whole project now but it'll take quite the time. So I'm asking here why it happened, or is there any possible solution as to I could recover my project codes? Thanks!

Comment: This is a wake-up call to start using a version control like `git`. Everything can be happened while you're coding; crash, RAM broken, hdd crash, etc. Make a backup

Comment: @ישואוהבאותך as he said, start using a vcs and also start keeping remote backups on Github or any cloud vcs of your choice to keep it safe from failing local storage.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio shows wrong file contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249677/android-studio-shows-wrong-file-contents)

Answer (score 1):

> is there any possible solution as to I could recover my project codes?

**Yes**. You have few options to recover your project. One option is **revert** your project code which I normally do.

Right click `app` ---> `Local History` ---> `Show History`

Then you can select which file or time you want to revert.