# My drawable xml file is showing unknown character

Tags: android, android-drawable, android-vectordrawable

The last activity that I did was adding a vector (check) and edited the color from black #000000 to white #ffffff. It successfully added. However, my other existing drawable vectors xml file changed into unknown character.

I have tried to rebuild and clean the project, even restart. But none of it helped me. Below are the xml codes of some drawable vectors (I have added a lot of vectors so I'm showing you a few.)

Also, when I run my project, there are no errors in Build.

ic_shopping_basket_black_24dp.xml

```
����   3z
 uwx abc_action_bar_home_description I 
ConstantValue   abc_action_bar_up_description  $abc_action_menu_overflow_description  abc_action_mode_done  !abc_activity_chooser_view_see_all  *abc_activitychooserview_choose_application  abc_capital_off  abc_capital_on  abc_font_family_body_1_material  abc_font_family_body_2_material   abc_font_family_button_material 
  abc_font_family_caption_material  "abc_font_family_display_1_material  "abc_font_family_display_2_material 
 "abc_font_family_display_3_material  "abc_font_family_display
```

ic_settings_black_24dp.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="WizardSettings">
    <option name="children">
      <map>
        <entry key="imageWizard">
          <value>
            <PersistentState>
              <option name="children">
                <map>
                  <entry key="imageAssetPanel">
                    <value>
                      <PersistentState>
                        <option name="children">
                          <map>
                            <entry key="actionbar">
                              <value>
                                <PersistentState>
                                  <option name="children">
                                    <map>
                                      <entry key="clipArt">
                                        <value>
                                          <PersistentState>
```

ic_send_black_24dp.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_ch"
        android:title="@string/save"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_check"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" /
```

ic_search_black_24dp.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.devcash">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Settings_UI.TermsActivity"
            android:label="@string/terms"
```

Comment: Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53249677).

Comment: Worked! Thank you.