# The emulateur of Android studio don't working error in ic_launcher_round.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

I have a problem with the emulator in android studio. It shows an error in file `ic_launcher_round.xml`. Saying this file failed to compile and the element must be declared on the xml code.

code in the `ic_launcher_round.xml` file :

```
<component name="libraryTable">
    <library name="Gradle: android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.1@aar">
        <CLASSES>
            <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/29f26e9a69885b61025619da3a205e0c/jars/classes.jar!/" />
            <root url= "file"
```

Thank you

[Here is the xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/io7cn.png)

[Here is the error statement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRXk0.png)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio shows wrong file contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249677/android-studio-shows-wrong-file-contents)

Comment: the xml file there is not complete. Is it a copy/paste issue?

Comment: @Wisthler Yes but  I did not do anything and I did not change anything at this file

Comment: @Zoe I think it's not the same problem :) :)

Comment: @AbdRahiimFilali it is. Look at the files: `<component>` is a tag in a .iml file, not in a drawable file.

Comment: I Tried the method and it did not work I think I should to complete the file

Answer (score 0):

you need to 3 file in the res/mipmap with thease names:

```
   ic_launcher.png
   ic_launcher_foreground.png
   ic_launcher_round.png
```

Comment: This is not exactly correct. The files do not need to be png images.  Further, they do not need to be with these names. The names must match what's in the manifest and file type may be any valid drawable resource, including XML.