# Android Studio replacing my xml layout (bug)

Tags: android, android-studio

I was previously working on a 1 month project using Android Studio. My xml layout was all well and good until I opened it up today and had the following as my xml code:

[image]

As you can see the preview is showing the correct data, but the code is not.

What happened, how can I retrieve my original code?

Some of the files were not backed up on a VCS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio shows wrong file contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249677/android-studio-shows-wrong-file-contents)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the android studio local history if your files were not backed up:

> Right click on your app folder - select "Local History" and "show history" to see your latest file that got changed

[image]