# Android Studio corruption strangeness: opening completely the wrong file

Tags: android-studio

Somehow my Android Studio project has become strangely corrupted.

When I open an xml layout file in `res/layout` it is actually opening a java file from the main source folder.

And opening `AndroidManifest.xml' opens some binary file from somewhere else.

But when I open these files from outside Android Studio, they're all fine and correct.

I've tried cleaning and rebuilding project, and I've tried invalidating caches and restarting, but still the same... what next?

Answer (score 2):

As reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54509482/4070848), the answer is to close Android Studio, delete the content of the following folder, then open Android Studio again:

```
C:\Users\my_user_name\.AndroidStudio3.4\system\caches
```