# XML file in android showing strange symbols like � (see detail)

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

This is the happening for the second time that the XML file in android is showing strange symbols in place of my original XML code . I left my laptop for 5 minutes and came across these horrible symbols on return. This code leads to build failed. How do i get my real code(textual code) for these files .
here's what my android studio shows :
[image]

Comment: Have you cleaned your project?

Comment: its also in java class ?

Comment: this time it's not in java . 
I have also cleaned my project , and it gets build failed .
I have edited the question , the code doesn't run .

Comment: goto file ->Invalidate Caches/Restart ->Invalidate/restart

Hope it will work fine for you

Comment: @JaiBahadur doesn't work

Comment: @SyedHissaan check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249677/android-studio-shows-wrong-file-contents

Comment: @NileshRathod the question you referred doesn't solve my problem . it's not duplicate, there were 2 files infected , 1 like the one mentioned in your posted link and 1 like the picture i pasted in my question . The question basically is different , the content in my case is not changed like the question you referred and those solutions don't fix my problem !
kindly remove the duplicate tag, to let me have a working solution for my problem

Comment: @SyedHissaan have u checked this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54044993/7666442 its a duplicate

Comment: @NileshRathod my android studio doesn't show tags like the post you referred , i had that problem earlier which i have fixed, but this problem is different . It would be nice to kindly observe both pictures and see how different these pictures are . i tried all the solutions as mentioned but none of them worked for me. my screen shows strange symbols like � while the post you mentioned is completely different . Had my problem been solved, i would be happy not wasting my time. Kindly recheck !

Comment: @SyedHissaan i know both  pictures are different  but its same android-studio bug my friend as confirmed by  for more information check this meta post : https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/380141/7666442

Comment: dear @NileshRathod if my problem was solved by those answers, why would i keep on adding comments !