# Disassemble all Java code in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

After the Windows shut down by the blue screen - all the Java code for my Android Studio project has changed

this is my MainActivity Codes After the change

[image]

Comment: check through notepad if it is actual file contents

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio shows wrong file contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249677/android-studio-shows-wrong-file-contents)