# Android Studio suddenly corrupted cannot read xml and java file

Tags: android-studio

I open my previous project and I checked it corrupted as you can see at the picture that I attached. It seems that Android Studio cannot read the file. It is happened after I update my window 8 to window 10 and import open CV library. I already tried restart my computer, after that I uninstall and reinstall Android Studio and I already tried invalidate cache memory.

```
? IHDR @ @?? ` U ??IDATx?  C ?Q?@ ; m۶m'  6 qֱm۶m۶ g<u     {S? w ,    Wʠ        ???  4C?  1??  xHa$  x ,$  x@R>!a}$  aGb? Xt a~ A   ?G5B T?G D   ? A\ IN ???  ??I {Ĥ  sf  #?f  ?? p 1   ? j#?U &? w?   A? ? ?[ζ   ?O   5ܿrg R  gI @ o<7  F `" y ?Ͳ? aH47?k  +?M} %n  kD?      ;  n  W  8  #$Ǧ8 C4  X؇? ?  R9Z  ?D ? BQ#>"  ? A     ?E $? ? ] ???GlVH ?Q!  < e  ,Z Dlv? R# #  ,P  e<= e  @? ) ". ?  Xz @) 0   A= \ % b(b 7F?? x  ?b   ؎    ? c?  &4  ?b Ǵ???m\    EYQ  wƒ   }| ?    "??  ?; Æo @ 2$    ?w Б a Z   ?? D" H ?~" EQ?  ? >( q  ( K? %ٗn Ē    /? ++     IEND B`
```

[image: it appear symbol that really weird]

Comment: This helped me. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54509482/9346054

Answer (score 1):

Try deleting this folder `C:\Users\user\.AndroidStudio3.*\system\caches` manually.

Answer (score 1):

If you have any backup of your project then add those backup files bcz I remember that when I got that error last month I tried everything but didn't get file back.