# How to fix the issue 'when Android Studio automatically converting some code into symbols'

Tags: android, android-studio

Android Studio automatically converts some java and xml code to unrecognizable symbols. Issue started when I updated Android studio two days back.

I do replaced the symbol code with my java and xml code, when I restart the android studio the same issue repeats.

My gradle file looks like

```
compileSdkVersion 29
buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
defaultConfig {
    ...
    targetSdkVersion 29
    ...
}
```

dependencies {

```
...
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
...
```

}

How it looks when it converts automatically,

����   3 f
 + M m    * N n    * O o    * P p    * Q q    * R �    * S �    * T �    * U �    * V �

this is color.xml how it want,

```
<color name="colorPrimary">#5d3e8a</color>
<color name="colorPrimaryDark">#4a316e</color>
```

Comment: try the `clear cache and restart` or copy your project to a new location and try or uninstall and reinstall AS on a different drive

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio shows wrong file contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249677/android-studio-shows-wrong-file-contents)