# Damage in XML files

Tags: xml, android-studio, kotlin

Suddenly all my XML files turn into something strange, I didn't do anything wrong. It was working 10 minutes ago. what should I do?

[image]

[image]

Comment: The second screenshot does not look like an xml file, so it won't pass that validation.

Comment: @Arjan It was xml file, it was splash screen

Comment: it may have been an xml file, but it is not any more. The lines `package kotlin.contracts` and `import kotlin.internal.ContractsDsl` indicate that the file is now Kotlin code.

Comment: I don't know what has happened, maybe the file contents was replaced by mistake. It's also possible that your editor is confused, so it might be a good idea to close it down and restart it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio shows wrong file contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249677/android-studio-shows-wrong-file-contents)

Comment: try to resync gradle and rebuild project. If no luck then File->Invalidate caches/Restart

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this issue few days back.
In my case,I had uninstalled and downloaded latest version of android studio.
It worked for me!
I suggest you reinstall android studio

Answer (score 1):

I will suggest you to uninstall your Android Studio old version and install **[Android Studio Preview release Canary 12](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview)**. That fixed this type of bugs.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but moving the project from partition C to partition D solved the problem.