# Android Studio behaving unnaurally after update to 3.5.2

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, gradle

There are various types of problems occurring after updating Android Studio to 3.5.2 and it's plugins. Some of them are:

1. Converted all XML codes to some unknown non-processable text format.
2. Failing gradle syncs
3. Android XML attributes like `padding`, `layout_margin` are shown as *Unknown Attributes*
4. `LinearLayouts` are being deployed without throwing errors like *Missing width or height*
5. `ImageButton` is not being able to process image automatically to given size.

Codes are included below from different files:

**XML of a simple view**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".view.HomeActivity"
    android:padding="18dp"> <!-- Padding: No such attribute -->

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/appTitleText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textSize="28sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:fontFamily="@font/comfortaa_variablefont_wght"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
        <!-- Margin:  No such attribute -->

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**XML of a deformed view**

```
�PNG


IHDR   �   �   ��o�   tEXtSoftware Adobe ImageReadyq�e<  �IDATx��]}�$�w�2#+�$'�O����#w~$.��
�;0�M��6'x{E�?�O1�Q?b�0Y&�h���^��Vcrk�d
L��]�da�eR����uuUw����t��<^��ꞩ߾zU��jC��&I��C�C�?�YQK���Cm�h.|��/����    �D���~_�}�����A3�t��
��)����k~Y�|^d�as��q��I�ڧ�n�/�^�҅B�S�"=T�ڥ�^�eZ�Â�bЬO���o>�T�9߄So���7g��v����n��{��ۖ�)�JP�V%�j�����.��ˆ�>�;�W�c�?fЬ:�7H,�����`�I8��Ih6�P*Ah9�N�kM�G�P�B<p�#^lI˄u��ׂf�)�T���]u�9b���>��c��>�%�B�o���G���K�P*��|Q���Vk��B��Ҁ���9ӄ����~�o���W�~�w1h�C��"ˑ��@c��jEl   Ht=m'

�Ի��l��8�7�4`anAZ�C�9�J<���A���S��T���:
GqTv�RY��6�td����W ��!  �g���b���tZ�"=wfN�M��w���;�"����!�k���<t�C0y|Rv�B9h�P��
��� ��$���|�    ��y;|冯�GG����Z��Tb�)��H& �E|K!I5>@���64K������#�'� (�V��P�\���V�N� Yکǎ�J��5�j<7�,�~�Ҵ�
`H��g
u���raZ\/y�6���� Y]�z����ƈ�fY����nM�)겠m��L�%>+� �4kMNXF�%M�7vЕ9�.I�0 ��r�]Q�H>��5���oU"�j��o5�9����u�=�/�\�Z>�:��Xl�$i*{6��i�fK�g"�@`�$[L:I&�z�G(͖���ŉ6��MJ�r-҃N�c���]$MZ�iB�VI?�ݓ3�F��1�����j�]�N�_(x�X�\��Y�i3��0�i�P��   4���K�wCf7i�O��t�v���KQ��#x��4[������K��?E�����n�-h-���k)��@�;��z�ӽT�k�������ֶ�ؔkZ�h�JK|���Ru`�MQ��aO��[�f�����m��V��g~�A�u��!��u�ϼ�L���K+�A��'�JN7�+�/_P�B� 塲� �5ȺN�g��$�e��\(�zAT��Ȯ�nJ��z�E� �f%@c\R9��4<���0���\P].���5�k�_�7m��l�~��=�ZX8��RT����p��C0rud-���-h����O����{��T����0�%m ��� µ�,��m[��]���뿂�,�/�N����#?~Fo�7ľ��C3��Թ]s��&V*��W? ���t�ĔWϯ���r�{���7�
�H��=�9���l��|F�6
��������1�4W��Qp��A�xnj������LF/嘗���Y�4��?�P�Z9 ��  ��������T��#x2�����c{�w
Y_�?����A��_�vϠ�
E�U�w�&���������7{��B*Рs��.�a��Qh�א7�%���b��b��H��Z���+���,�Y0jC��'}'�of���c����ߓHdH�6����^��|���!x��
����;�l�x7v���A7��o}��u�=�M!Z�
��J��գ�`ϟ��mNFbW���:��J�T�{��NL�ʂ�V��'HZ����էי��.[�l��y���Y"�C����j�+7���g�#��'���]�O�FGI޿mHir��Wu����W6�\�{.�;�d>M�`[c�cۣ� ����`����7&'��K��U�����ϵQR�^�{ֳ��r��J�Ӵ���5��L��S��u�����8��c�Dɗ�   ���0�2&�ǕOʛdR��u&=���s��y%��1}?l{� bAǈ�4���* �w�^�e����g�鏜��ڐw�?�,�~��<1)�#���>볯w=།���W�٫4X 4�
�8����`�:k��A��충�   �됳���<Ng?m�d�o�F��ykFʤmĘ�C
��gC3�ۂv���a2�AA�Eep�BE�}I���I��P>�W��]�O�h���h�gO/Wv}  �!
��r���-�\�`}��ԀX��t�
�>.t�1�g[���$��އ..�gZ��ƱX���,�̞4m\��4}�� ��.,�%�Q�ѧQ�O�sûA�̏4�-QЬ�
�8��]�A{���k��Z���cFԶy&&��Nc��O�s�v��C-�9��P4����Q5~�J�Ԇ��Ϗ��
SK�DLݍR�h����D�JRC3.����    5���niB'���a7��?����n��g��iR��
�L�8�1)k���dy�5됛�)M���4�9�\~}�����X��9
��y��`�ׯӮ�b#ji\�l-�V�D8M\~���d��0B/Z�'�q��OF������:$�i)�a&����5�d��>;
XZN�e}��i,�~5��ב�7m�%6:��][�G�NG�UL��X`-�2��:�{�ICVxXf�]'� ���4I'��̦����u]�_a���ϕ^��4����)䴟�s5u��)iVxc�t1����0=��e��'i/u�ɪ��r��>I��
�̣�s�G_j;L���/����eS�D?`;��9�/��(��4����
Y�}��b0,;����L�vcGO�S��yZ[`nrWyj�X�m}(����o�'�S@�>��HH!1��di���Y�%K�s�i��J�[I�|�%]a?��l6�N^ �
```

**Gradle file**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.oobs.juncos"
        minSdkVersion 22
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.core:core-ktx:+"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
```

I have tried rechecking my gradle and other files but no improvement.

Comment: Hi @Saswata I am facing same issue after updating android studio.Sometimes all XML & Java file converted to some unknown non-processable text format.

Comment: Yes you can find your `XML` when you open code with Notepad

Comment: @JahanviKariya Hi but unfortunately we are facing various kinds of issues which changes time to time so looking for a permanent fix.

Comment: @JahanviKariya Hi following your idea I have wrote a temporary solution below, please do add your observations and ways on edit if you feel so.

Comment: Your **XML of a deformed view** is a png -picture ;-)

Comment: @Simson ok, but didn't see that coming... 

Comment: Not a duplicate, but we have e.g. this previous report about the "corrupt" files: [Android Studio shows wrong file contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249677/android-studio-shows-wrong-file-contents).

Answer (score 0):

**A stable solution** *(For Linux users)*

Uninstall the whole Android Studio and re-install without importing previous settings will fix the problem.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the caches folder from Android Studio? maybe your old settings is not imported properly.