# Project files are randomly getting encrypted / corrupted?

Tags: android, android-studio, error-handling

One second I'm working on my Android project with everything building and running fine. The next thing I know all of the data in my files are replaced with random characters.

[image]
I've tried

- invalidating cache
- reverting back to a local history save

Is there's a way for me to fix this or prevent this?

Comment: Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53249677).

Comment: @MikeM. thank you for the link. That link took me down a rabbit hole of different solutions but **none of them seemed to fix the problem**

Comment: Yeah, that's why I don't automatically close these as duplicates. I've never had this issue, so I'm not sure which are valid solutions. Sorry that didn't help, but I don't really have anything else to suggest.

Comment: I get this issue many time and it has a very simple solution just close your studio ide then go to your android studio path and delete the caches folder from it and again restart the ide all things will be fine  check this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249677/android-studio-shows-wrong-file-contents