# Android Studio3.5 suddenly cannot resolve symbols

Tags: android, android-studio, android-studio-3.5

**Android Studio3.5.3** suddenly **cannot resolve symbol xxxx error occurs**. 
and even **cannot load some java file**, showing wrong characters with **UTF-8** encoding.

Well I searched online and tried the `Invalid & Restart` methods, but that did not work at all.

Someone please help me out.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried syncing the project with gradle files?

Comment: @isaaaaame yes. tried but not worked neither

Comment: maybe there is a problem with one of the dependencies

Comment: @isaaaaame umm, well, the project source was ok just last day. nothing changed.

Comment: tyr clean build of the project through command line and add `--stacktrace` on the end

Comment: This problem? [Android Studio shows wrong file contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249677/android-studio-shows-wrong-file-contents)

Comment: @MarkusKauppinen thanks. this save my time.

Answer (score 1):

As @MarkusKauppinen provided post: [Android Studio shows wrong file contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249677/android-studio-shows-wrong-file-contents)

This is the key:
**`Delete the caches folder: C:\Users\my_user_name\.AndroidStudio3.5\system\caches`**

Answer (score 0):

please try this
"File" -> "Invalidate Caches...", and select "Invalidate and Restart"