# Android Studio project doesn't work properly both java or xml

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio for long enough, but never experienced this kind of error. I don't know how to fix it. All XML is not usual, it has *component* or *javadoc* or something and all java file suddenly has a child. I don't understand why the project turn to be like that.

Here some preview of my error :

[image: this is the java file]

[image: this is the xml file]

So, what should I do?

Comment: Did you try to invalidate cache and restart?

Comment: @WahdatKashmiri yes I've tried, but still doesn't change anything

Comment: There's a known bug in Android Studio. It shows the wrong file contents but they are actually okay on the disk. Just have a look at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249677/android-studio-shows-wrong-file-contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249677/android-studio-shows-wrong-file-contents)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio shows wrong file contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249677/android-studio-shows-wrong-file-contents)

Comment: Ok, lemme check @MarkusKauppinen

Comment: thank you, it worked @MarkusKauppinen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I found how to fixed the problem. Go to

`C:\Users\(user name)\.AndroidStudio3.5\system` then delete caches file. Done!

Answer (score 0):

Your class is actually named:
`FragmentHome.java` and you instead have a class named `PhoneUtil`

And your package name is incorrect:

`com.android.ex.chips`

it should be:

`id.technow.kjur`

in addition to this, your XML is not a layout XML. It is a ProjectCodeStyleConfiguration XML snippet.

So it is IMHO, you have copied files to the wrong places.

Comment: I don't think so, because I've open the project and do some work there everyday, but today when I open my AS it just turn to be like that. Error's everywhere