# Start the android studio and get this error

Tags: android, android-studio

I do not understand why when booting android studio up again like that?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53249677).

Comment: Does that article work with this project? Help me !

Comment: What specifically are you having difficulty with? Did you follow the directions in [the top-voted answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53476487)?

Comment: I did exactly as instructed, delete cache and create another directory but still not working, please help me !!

Comment: That's an invalid AndroidManifest.xml file. Did the file contain that markup before? If not it would appear that it's a caching issue and that Android Studio's cache has become corrupted. Clearing the cache and/or recreating the project in another directory as recommended in the answer that @mike-m linked will fix the issue. If that's not the problem you're trying to solve, we'd love to help, but we'd need some more detail on the circumstances of the problem before we can do so.

Answer (score 0):

Please delete the android studio cache from your system. Cache folder will be in your `Users` folder

if your Android studio version is 3.5 then or if not go to correspondent version

```
[your_pc_name]/.AndroidStudio3.5/system/caches
```

still didn't help delete

```
[your_pc_name]/.gradle/caches
```

These folders will be hidden in the Users folder so you have to unhide all. Hopes this will help you.

Comment: I did exactly as instructed, delete cache and create another directory but still not working, please help me !!