# How can I fix errors in my colors.xml file?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-layout, android-resources

I am new to Android programming and running on version 3.6.3. I am having a Build failed: error 1; XML document must start and end with the same entity.

````
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="androidx.constraintlayout.widget"> //This one is errorTagged with "Element manifest must be declaired."

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="9" //This one is tagged with "Tag start is not closed" but when I close it with '/>', it changes to 'Unexpected ending.'```
````

Comment: Paste your manifest file code complete one. Also, the error seems to be in the manifest file. Then y u mentioned coors.xml?

Comment: Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53249677).

Comment: Hello Prajwal W, I mentioned colors.xml because I got the error from there and that code I have copied and just pasted from the same file and not the manifest. Hope you understand!

Comment: Hi, in manifest you don't need to <manifest>, see my color.xml in my answer as an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <color name="colorPrimary">#008577</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#ff0000</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#00ff00</color>
    <color name="mtrl_textinput_default_box_stroke_color" tools:override="true">#000</color>
</resources>
```