# strange code in the styles.xml file in android studio

Tags: xml, android-studio

I have been working on a project for a while now and everything was ok until I had to open my styles.xml file (for the first time) so I found this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="AndroidLayouts">
    <shared>
      <config />
    </shared>
  </component>
  <component name="ChangeListManager">
    <list default="true" id="3b5010f6-f8e2-42f0-a710-49ed4d49b9ca" name="Default Changelist" comment="" />
    <option name="EXCLUDED_CONVERTED_TO_IGNORED" value="true" />
    <option name="SHOW_DIAL
```

and since then, I can't run my app. It shows me this error: "XML document structures must start and end within the same entity."

what should I do?

Comment: Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53249677).

Comment: thanks, but it didn't work for me... so I just copied the code from a styles.xml file from another project and now it is running without errors :)