# Why my java files is opening in encoded format on android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Till yesterday all files are ok, but today when I tried to open java files in android studio, its showing encoded format like:

[image]

Since I have backup, I reverted that, but unable to understand the root cause any help would be appreciable.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Android Studio shows wrong file contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249677/android-studio-shows-wrong-file-contents)

Comment: This is a bug in android studio and is caused because of encodings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your Build folder is corrupt you need to rebuild the project.

First things first

File->Invalidate caches/Restart

[image]

If this doesn't work try rebuilding your project

[image]

Build->Clean Project
then
Build->rebuild project

If still no luck? Close Android Studio Try these:

1: Clear Android Studio Cache
Delete this folder
C:\Users%username%.AndroidStudio4.0\system\caches
Check if the problem is solved

2: Rebuild manually
Delete this folder and try again
C:\Users%username%\AndroidStudioProjects<project name>\app\build

Comment: Clear Android Studio Cache Delete this folder C:\Users%username%.AndroidStudio4.0\system\caches Check if the problem is solved: This worked in my case: thanks

Answer (score 0):

> The encoding used to compile your project is specified in the
> build.gradle files. The default, which is used when no specific
> encoding is specified, is UTF-8. We strongly recommend you use UTF-8
> encoding whenever possible. The Android development tools create UTF-8
> encoded projects by default, the Android Gradle plugin uses UTF-8 by
> default, and Android Lint will warn whenever it encounters XML files
> that are not using UTF-8

Add this in your **`build.gradle`** section.

```
android {
 compileOptions.encoding = 'UTF-8'

 ...
 }
```

OR

[image]

Then **`Clean-Rebuild-Restart`**