# How to resolve android studio formatting error?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm sorry for the title of my question but that's the best title i could come up with....
It seems like my android studio project just got butchered from one day to the next. When i open some of my java file, i see nothing related to my code same thing with most of my xml files, but when i navigate to those files in my file explorer and open them same files with notepad i then see the correct content.[A screen shot of one of my java files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kzsx8.png)
[And one of my xml files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRMbN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a common problem in Android studio
Please follow this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/63027190/7793652