# Android Studio automatic codes cut/shuffle between different pages

Tags: android, android-studio

Hello Android Studio experts, I'm facing a weird issue with Android Studio itself. I have been observing a weird issue with Android Studio where the effortfully written codes are getting shuffled between random pages of the project. See the attached image. You can see the codes of `styles.xml` page are displayed in a Java file and also see the icon of Java page is displayed differently. How to fix it?
While I'm writing this description, I'm upgrading current SDK Platform 29 version 4 to 29 version 5.
[image: Android Studio problem]

Comment: First Invalidate / Caches And restart . If not works delete .iml files and .gradle folder in project and then open android studio

Comment: I do "Invalidate Caches / Restart" in once or twice a week. I have deleted the caches folder as discussed in https://stackoverflow.com/a/54509482/1617737. I'll observe for some days and come back with my observations. I have checked just 2 projects and corrected the codes after lot of efforts. I haven't checked for others yet. Some places I even found human unreadable characters. Don't know what's wrong.