# All resource code weirdly formatted - android

Tags: android, android-studio

Every single one of the resource code files in my project has been replaced by some weird code which I have never seen before.  Looks something like this:

```
<component name="libraryTable">


<library name="Gradle: com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:17.0.0@aar">
    <CLASSES>
      <root url="jar://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/796a0b4c180aac786f34fc6b1a4b1d26/jetified-play-services-tasks-17.0.0/jars/classes.jar!/" />
      <root url="file://$USER_HOME$/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/796a0b4c180aac786f34fc6b1a4b1d26/jetified-play-services-tasks-17.0.0/res" />
    </CLASSES>
    <JAVADOC />
    <SOURCES />
  </library>
</component>
```

what have i done and how can i fix this?????

Comment: Very nice indented indeed. Makes it all so readable.

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53249677.