# Few xml files in my android studio is showing some weird text

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

Have a Look at my xml file
[image: Have a Look at my xml file]

I don't know why many of my xml files are showing weird text in my android project I tried to uninstall and install the android studio and facing the same problem.

����   4  com/example/hibengaluru/R$menu  java/lang/Object  com/example/hibengaluru/R  menu cart I

()V

ConstantValue Code InnerClasses 1

Comment: Related? [Android Studio shows wrong file contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249677/android-studio-shows-wrong-file-contents)

Comment: Are the files okay if you open them in some other editor and not in Android Studio?