# Android Studio shows files with the wrong contents

Tags: android, android-studio

When I open a project, every Java file displays with a J icon instead of C as normal.

When I open manifest file, it shows code from another file.
[image]

When I open one of the .java files, it shows the manifest's content.
[image]

I am using version Arctic Fox 2020.3.1 patch 3.

Comment: just transfer your code to another location and open again your code in android studio

Comment: great, it works. But is there anyway I can keep this old location? I don't want to change the project path.

Comment: Yes once you change location then keep in your old location i think its work

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio shows wrong file contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249677/android-studio-shows-wrong-file-contents)

Comment: I don't know, I used the solution of @DeepParsania. Maybe I'll try your link next time it happens.

Answer (score -1):

1. Close Android Studio
2. Delete the `.gradle` folder and restart Android Studio
3. Wait for some time to sync the Project.
4. Just do `Clean project` and you are good to go

That's it. Your Issue will be fixed.

Comment: Thank for your help. I tried this but it not works.