# Why my code in android studio is auto changed?

Tags: android

My code in android studio is auto changed. I don't know which is the reason for this?

[image: ?]

Comment: I think you have used the flutter SDK on your computer without any proper guidance.

Comment: Possibly this situation: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53249677.

Comment: Generally it happens when android studio stopped unexpectedly. Try to clean cache and rebuild it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what all the `NULL` characters at the bottom means, maybe you opened the file using an editor that didn't understand those characters and you saved it improperly? You could just delete them.

This looks like an res `xml` and you have two different kinds of `comments`. `/* */` **AND** `<!-- -->`.

If this is supposed to be an xml document remove the `/* */` comment characters and replace them with `<!-- -->` comment characters.

Comment: i think my code is encode or my computer is hacked. It's just a normal java file but it's converted like that.