# My every project files and class suddenly turned into an strange format

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, iunknown

Everything was good. Today, I opened Android Studio, and every kotlin class code and even layout and value files turned into another format like XML. I don't know what kind of strange reason it is.
I have been trying to fix this for 2 days now. even though I opened my files into some other editors(sublime, notepad)but the problem is still there.

I am attaching some screenshots [MainActivity.kt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLTDJ.png).

I also tried these couple of things below

File > Sync project with Gradle files. Result: didn't solve my problem.
File > Invalidated cache/restart. Result: didn't solve my problem.

Comment: You might have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/53249677.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't know how to fix your issue. However, I'd advise you to look into version control (git). Version control allows you to easily roll-back any changes (among other things). This will help you avoid such problems in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
Right-click on the file (e.g.: MainActivity.kt),
then click on "Open In", it will open your explorer window.
At this point open that file, which now you see in your explorer window, in a notepad, make a change (e.g.: adding a space where there is already a blank space)
and save the file.
Now Android Studio should see it correctly or, if not, try to restart Android Studio.
If that works, do the same for all suddenly-changed files.

Comment: Thank you so much man you save me ,i was trying to solve this for a weak now